# How to Connect Old Versions of Android Device to Android Studio (Bumblebee)

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee, android-device-manager

The Android Studio version of Bumblebee seems only to support the Android 11+ versions to connect devices through Wi-Fi wirelessly and pare devices through paring code.

But I currently only have a Samsung Galaxy Note4, which is the version of Android 6.0.1.
How can I connect to Android Studio and run Android Apps on my Note4? Please provide some learning resources or support, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top right corner of Android Studio, you see this toggle list, and click on "**Troubleshoot Device Connections**".

[Find "**Troubleshoot Device Connection**" on the top right corner toggle list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETJ1r.png)

After that, follow the given steps to "**Rescan Devices**", and "**Enable USB Debugging**". Then you'll see your device appears in the toggle list. If not, press "**Restart ADB(Android Debug Bridge) server**" to find your device.

[Steps provided by Troubleshoot Device Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEHGN.png)

Finally, press **Finish** to complete the task.

All in all, when I tried to find out how can I connect my old old version of the Android device to the AS, I got nothing on the internet. So I asked this question here, but eventually, I fix it on my own.

So I hope this question helps.